# Updated substring in NSAttributedString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsattributedstring

How I can replace substring in NSMutableAttributedString without adding static range number?
I have a label with this text: `@"12 friends"`, I want to replace 12 (number of friends) with another number (and use the same attributes for this substring) once that it will come from the server, and I can not use the below approach since the number of digits is unknown:

```
/*wrong approach*/
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
[mutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2) withString:counter];
[label setAttributedText:mutableAttributedString];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the label will always read "x friends" then why not just use a formatted string and pass in the number of friends as a parameter. Of course you could make this whole thing variable for localization, etc. but the basic idea is this:

```
NSInteger numberFromServer = ...

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d friend%@",numberFromServer,((numberFromServer != 1) ? @"s" : @"")];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

[label setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Comment: Yes, in this case it always will be "x friends" but I made my questions more generic for the next times, What should I do in dynamic cases? 
do have any idea ?